# How do I change Motherboard firmware settings from UEFI to Legacy boot so that I can use Paragon Hard Disk Manager?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

I have been using this excellent software program, Paragon Hard Disk Manager, for many years for backing up and restoring select files. In order to use its recovery media (created on CD or thumb drive) to boot into WindowsPE one has to change the motherboard firmware settings from UEFI to Legacy boot.

Since I upgraded my computer's internal drive to a solid-state drive, although I can still get into the motherboard firmware, but cannot see the Legacy boot option anymore.

How can I get into all the data that has been backed up to an external drive for many years?

Comment: You write "Since I upgraded my computer's internal drive to a solid-state drive, although I can still get into BIOS, the option to change to a Legacy boot is no longer available." <-- that's not possible. It's there. A hard drive upgrade won't get rid of it!! You should share what the make and model is

Comment: You write "How can I get into all the data that has been backed up to an external drive for many years?" <-- maybe you can share a bit about the file format used by paragon hard disk manager, that can be kind of a separate question really.. like how can you access paragon (image? backup?) without using paragon e.g. copying. But you might be able to with paragon so that's a question too.. You will find answers for sure it's not a hard problem. People will know

Comment: this might help https://notebooktalk.net/forum/60-notebook-manufacturers/   they have manucacturer specific sections like notebookforum had also this forum that some people went to after notebookforum closed https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/

Answer (score 0):

Ask your mainboard manfacturer how to access the legacy boot CSM ("compatibility support module"). If that fails do the following:

1. Use a different machine with supports legacy boot
2. Restore your data to an external disk.
3. Connect the external disk to your old machine.

Comment: Worth noting that CSM is another term for Legacy

Comment: There is no standard for describing that BIOS option. That is why I mentionned all possible terms I could imagine.

Comment: yes that's very reasonable to mention all possible terms, (legacy mode on, BIOS mode on, CSM mode on, UEFI  OFF), but worth mentioning that they are terms for the same thing. Could say Legacy/CSM rather than Legacy CSM.

Comment: That is better! I love precision, no joking here.